# Ionic: http://localhost/callback?code= could not be loaded because ERR_connection_refused

Tags: ionic-framework, oauth-2.0, cordova-plugins, linkedin-api

I'm trying to implement the sign-in with linkedin functionality in the ionic using rest-api method.

```
linkedinLogin() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.linkedinPage().then(success => {
        alert(success.access_token);
      },(error) => {
        alert(error);
      });
    });
  }

  linkedinPage(): Promise<any> {
    var self = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var browserRef = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?client_id=' + this.clientId + '&redirect_uri=' + this.redirect_uri + '&scope=' + this.appScope + '&response_type=code&state=' + this.state, '_blank', 'location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes');
      browserRef.addEventListener("loadstart", (event) => {
        if((event.url).indexOf(this.redirect_uri) === 0) {
          try {
            var requestToken = (event.url).split("code=")[1].split("&")[0];
            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            this.http.post("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?client_id='xxxx'&client_secret='xxxxxx'&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback&grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + requestToken,
            {headers: headers})
            .subscribe(function(data){
              resolve(data);
              alert(data);
            })

          } catch(e) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                browserRef.close();
              }, 10);
            }
        }
        else {
          browserRef.addEventListener("exit", function(event) {
            reject("The linkedin sign in flow was canceled");
        });
        }
      });
  });
  }
```

I'm able to redirect to the linkedin page and ente my credentials allowing the linkedin to access the permission. After I'm getting a error message in the browser as 
[image: error message]

Can someone say me why I'm facing this error and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It is because linkedin will never allow you to access their API form localhost because of CROS. Did you try running your application in real device? If not try it on real device and view console you can find accurate error from there.

Comment: yes, I've executed it in the emulator & how can I see the error for the apps that are running in the emulator.

Comment: You can see console of emulator